# Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $templateRequest <- $animate <- cfpLoadingBar <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have Problem with my angular JS application I have used nuget to upgrade from AngularJS 1.3.0 Beta to 1.3.16 and it I have the following error:

> angular.js:4183 Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency
>   found: $templateRequest <- $animate <- cfpLoadingBar <- $http <-
>   $templateRequest <- $compile
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/cdep?p0=%24templateRequest%20%…oadingBar%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24compile

I tried adding $injector to home controller like this but it didn't resolve the issue. Could someone help me?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app');

    var HomeController = function ($scope, $location, $injector, authService, userInfoService, homeService) {
       };

    app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$location','$injector','authService', 'userInfoService', 'homeService', HomeController]);

}());
```

Comment: try to  put app.controller after var app = .... and var HomeController at the end.

Comment: `cfpLoadingBar` is using `ngAnimate`.  1.3 did a lot with animation.  This is were I'd focus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solve the problem by upgrade cfpLoadingBar from v0.3.0 to v0.8.0